# How do you create node-soap wsdl file?

Tags: node.js, web-services, schema, decorator, node-soap

I am reading node-soap documentation on how to create a server web-service. I understand everything concerning creating a web-service except how myservice.wsdl (as per the code snippet below) is created. If someone has created a web-service as per the node-soap documentation please guide me as to how I should create the wsdl file. Thank you in advance.

```js
  var myService = {
      MyService: {
          MyPort: {
              MyFunction: function(args) {
                  return {
                      name: args.name
                  };
              },

              // This is how to define an asynchronous function.
              MyAsyncFunction: function(args, callback) {
                  // do some work
                  callback({
                      name: args.name
                  });
              },

              // This is how to receive incoming headers
              HeadersAwareFunction: function(args, cb, headers) {
                  return {
                      name: headers.Token
                  };
              },

              // You can also inspect the original `req`
              reallyDetailedFunction: function(args, cb, headers, req) {
                  console.log('SOAP `reallyDetailedFunction` request from ' + req.connection.remoteAddress);
                  return {
                      name: headers.Token
                  };
              }
          }
      }
  };

  var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('myservice.wsdl', 'utf8');

  //http server example
  var server = http.createServer(function(request,response) {
      response.end('404: Not Found: ' + request.url);
  });

  server.listen(8000);
  soap.listen(server, '/wsdl', myService, xml);

  //express server example
  var app = express();
  //body parser middleware are supported (optional)
  app.use(bodyParser.raw({type: function(){return true;}, limit: '5mb'}));
  app.listen(8001, function(){
      //Note: /wsdl route will be handled by soap module
      //and all other routes & middleware will continue to work
      soap.listen(app, '/wsdl', myService, xml);
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the Node.js SOAP modules (to my knowledge) create a WSDL file for you.

What you can do is use a service to create the WSDL.

An example is http://marin.jb.free.fr/wsdl/, you can use this to create the WSDL file for whatever service you wish.

Comment: Thank you. I feel a bit stupid. I should have looked for online tools. Thank you so much. You might be able to help me with my next question around this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50987471/how-do-you-get-the-server-url-to-give-to-the-client-when-using-node-soap-or-stro